# Why is my db query not respecting AND constraint?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have written a function that should return objects constrained by AND criteria. But it seems to honour only last criteria. For example if I query "dog cat", it seems to return all results containing "cat" disregarding "dog". What am I doing wrong? This is my function:

```
public function all($keyword, $offset = 0, $limit = 10) {
    if(isset($keyword) && !empty($keyword)) {
        $sql = 'SELECT id, date, title FROM wiki WHERE ';
        $keywords = explode(" ", $keyword);
        $i=0;
        $count = count($keywords);
        foreach($keywords as $word) {
            $sql = $sql . '( lower(title) LIKE lower(:keyword' . $i . ') ) ';
            if($i != $count - 1) $sql = $sql . "AND ";
            $i++;
        }
        $sql = $sql . 'ORDER BY update_date DESC LIMIT :offset,:limit;';
        $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        for($i = 0; $i < count($keywords);  $i++) {
            $word = "%" .  $keywords[$i] . "%";
            $query->bindParam(":keyword$i", $word, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        }
        $limit = (int) $limit;
        $offset = (int) $offset;
        $query->bindParam(':limit', $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $query->bindParam(':offset', $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);          
        $query->execute();
        $list = null;
        foreach($query->fetchAll() as $wiki) {
            $list[] = $wiki;
        }
        return $list;
    }
    return null;
}
```

The SQL generated is:

```
SELECT id, date, title FROM wiki WHERE ( lower(title) LIKE lower(:keyword0) ) 
AND ( lower(title) LIKE lower(:keyword1) ) 
ORDER BY update_date DESC LIMIT :offset,:limit;
```

I have checked and keywords i.e. "dog" and "cat" respectively have index 0 and 1 and are injected to :keyword0 and :keyword1.

Comment: Show us the actual final SQL this all generates for you.

Comment: Well a first flaw in your logic is that anything which contains `day` also contains `a`

Comment: Also, I don't believe that you can bind limit and offset in this way

Comment: @MarkBaker You can if you bind it as integer, but I would recommend casting it to an integer as well e.g. `(int) $limit`

Comment: a beautiful day was just an example. same thing happens with dog and cat.

Comment: final sql: SELECT id, date, title FROM wiki WHERE ( lower(title) LIKE lower(:keyword0) ) AND ( lower(title) LIKE lower(:keyword1) ) ORDER BY update_date DESC LIMIT :offset,:limit; PDO replaces :keywordx, :offset and :limit

Comment: @SureshSubedi please edit your question and add this query

Comment: Side node. you don't need `lower()` at all in MySQL just to match strings. Instead, set a proper collation (if column collation is not already right).

Comment: I have tried. That gives "#1253 - COLLATION 'utf8_general_mysql500_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' " and "#1253 - COLLATION 'utf8_general_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' " for collation of type utf8_bin. SQL eg: `SELECT id, date, title FROM wiki WHERE ( title LIKE "%ge%" COLLATE utf8_general_ci)`